# How to count users using Microsoft graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

According to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?#count-parameter
I should be able to get the count by using
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?count=true
but it doesn't work...
Also I found that if I add ConsistencyLevel: eventual to the request header I do get a count but
it's not in the documentation so I'm not sure the count is the real user count

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$search="displayName:wa"&$orderby=displayName&$count=true
    ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q-5_http) which tells we need to use   ConsistencyLevel: eventual

See also this article on the `$count` parameter:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http#count-parameter